# Memory doesn't get free with this structure resulting in a memory leak while using Zenject as a DI Container

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory, memory-leaks, zenject

I have next structure:

`TestFacade` is a `GameObject` that gets pooled.

```
    public class TestFacade : MonoBehaviour, IPoolable<IMemoryPool>, IDisposable
    {
        public class Factory : PlaceholderFactory<TestFacade> { }

        public class Pool : MonoPoolableMemoryPool<IMemoryPool, TestFacade> { }

        public Guid ID;

        private TestComponent _component;
        private TestRegistry _registry;
        private IMemoryPool _pool;

        [Inject]
        public void Construct(TestRegistry registry)
        {
            _component = new TestComponent(this);
            _registry = registry;
            ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public void OnSpawned(IMemoryPool pool)
        {
            _component.TestMethod();
            _pool = pool;
            _registry.Add(ID, this);
        }

        public void OnDespawned()
        {
            _pool = null;
            _registry.Remove(ID);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _pool.Despawn(this);
        }
    }
```

Logicaly, `TestComponent` doesn't exist without `TestFacade`, but I couldn't "bind" it (don't know how), so I create it myself in `TestFacade` making it coupled to `TestFacade`.

```
    public class TestComponent
    {
        private readonly TestFacade _testFacade;

        public TestComponent(TestFacade testFacade)
        {
            _testFacade = testFacade;
        }

        public void TestMethod()
        {
            Debug.Log(_testFacade.ID);
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

`TestFacade` fill this registry to keep a record of spawned `TestFacade`'s.

```
    public class TestRegistry
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Guid, TestFacade> _objects;

        public IReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, TestFacade> Objects => _objects;

        public TestRegistry()
        {
            _objects = new Dictionary<Guid, TestFacade>();
        }

        public void Add(in Guid id, TestFacade test)
        {
            _objects.Add(id, test);
        }

        public void Remove(in Guid id)
        {
            _objects.Remove(id);
        }
    }
```

`TestSpawner` handles spawning/despawning of `TestFacade` using `TestRegistry` and `TestFacade.Factory` (it seems logical, right?).

```
    public class TestSpawner : IInitializable, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TestFacade.Factory _testFactory;
        private readonly TestRegistry _registry;

        public TestSpawner(TestFacade.Factory testFactory, TestRegistry registry)
        {
            _testFactory = testFactory;
            _registry = registry;
        }

        public ref Guid Spawn()
        {
            var testFacade = _testFactory.Create();

            return ref testFacade.ID;
        }

        public void Despawn(in Guid id)
        {
            _registry.Objects[id].Dispose();
        }

        public void DespawnAll()
        {
            foreach (var testFacade in _registry.Objects.Values)
            {
                testFacade.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            // 1
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // 2
        }
```

And this is just a test script. All it does is requests to spawn new `TestFacade` every second using injected `TestSpawner`. Is this right usage of IoC principle and DI Container?

```
    public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Inject]
        private TestSpawner _testSpawner;

        private Guid _id;

        private bool set;

        private void Start()
        {
            StartCoroutine(RemoveEachTime());
        }

        private IEnumerator RemoveEachTime()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

            while (true)
            {
                if (set)
                {
                    _testSpawner.Despawn(in _id);
                    set = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    _id = _testSpawner.Spawn();
                    set = true;
                }

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have two scenes: `Scene1` and `Scene2`.

`Scene1` simply loads `Scene2`.

`Scene2` has `SceneContext` where I install all this logic.

```
    public class TestSceneInstaller : MonoInstaller
    {
        [Inject] private Settings _settings;

        public override void InstallBindings()
        {
            Container.Bind<TestRegistry>().AsSingle();
            Container.BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<TestSpawner>().AsSingle();

            Container.BindFactory<TestFacade, TestFacade.Factory>()
                .FromPoolableMemoryPool<TestFacade, TestFacade.Pool>(poolBinder => poolBinder
                    .WithInitialSize(2)
                    .FromComponentInNewPrefab(_settings.TestFacadePrefab)
                    .UnderTransformGroup("TestObjects"));
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class Settings
        {
            public GameObject TestFacadePrefab;
        }
    }
```

I've decided to use Memory Profiler to check what happens in memory.

My logic is that:

1. `Scene1` loads `Scene2` and unloads itself
2. `Scene2` installs all this logic
3. `TestScript` runs some logic
4. `Scene2` loads `Scene1` and unloads itself
5. All `TestFacade`'s `GameObjects` got destroyed, which means
   `TestComponent` gets destroyed too because it is not referenced by `TestFacade` anymore (right?). And basically whole structure should be destroyed? Nobody references `TestSpawner` so it should also go. Same goes for `TestRegistry`.

But, when I load `Scene2` again I notice that now I have 2 of everything.

Same happens 3rd time...

Did I messed something up?
Is the way I'm thinking wrong?

### Unity leak analysis

Memory Profiler tells me that `TestFacade` is a **Leaked Managed Shell**.

[image]

P.S. Also, I wouldn't mind any feedback regarding this structure, how I handle everything, e.g., usage of `Guid` struct as ID and passing it by `ref` to not copy it over and over again, etc.

Comment: Don't forget you are coding in Unity which like Unreal Engine is for making _games_ where performance is paramount; the last thing you want to do is follow _white-collar-business-practices_ where people spend more time worrying about dependency injection and writing unit tests than working on the problem at hand.  Both of these technologies use excessive reflection and/or dynamic proxies both of which will hurt.   Check out [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/design-patterns-singleton-and-dependency-injection.547033/) thread over at the Unity forums.  The comments by **ippdev** are _gold!_

Comment: Why the need for `ref` in the method `public ref Guid Spawn()`?  Why would you want to allow callers to modify `testFacade.ID`?

Comment: As for the leak, do you need a `MonoBehaviour.OnDisable()` somewhere?   Also, as for the _"leak",_ Unity is a **CLR Host** whereby it can and will **zap** out the **Primary App Domain** along with all your objects **including singletons** not just during runtime but also whilst using the **Editor**.  See also _[Details of disabling Domain and Scene Reload](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html)_.  What evidence that you have for a leak over the long-term?  Is it cumulative?

Comment: @MickyD, I checked out that thread, I was 50/50 use DI or not before and 50/50 after
About `ref`, no, I don't want anyone to modify `ID`, buuuut I also don't want to copy it every time

Comment: Also good point on Domain Reload, let me check it in the build

Comment: _"copy it every time"_ - `Guid` is a struct, thus a _value type_ and therefor much faster than reference types due to their ability to move about _on the stack_. :)

Comment: Well, I just checked it on the actual build and I was right. Memory Profiler tells me that `TestFacade` is a Leaked Managed Shell. [Here's a screenshot of snapshot](https://i.imgur.com/OoZU7TR.png)

Comment: _"Memory Profiler tells me that TestFacade is a Leaked Managed Shell"_ - oh no!!  I hope you don't mind but I have edited your question to include that little nugget.

Comment: Oh I wonder if its because the type is being whacked in a memory pool via `FromPoolableMemoryPool<>`.  What happens if you don't use a pool?

Comment: Well the thing is I need it to be a pool lol

Comment: The thing about pools is (and this applies to the ones in .NET), is that when you request an object instance, the pool looks for a pre-existing one and returns that, otherwise it creates a new one.  When you no longer need it, you hand it back.  However, and this depends on the type being whacked in the pool, care must be performed to ensure any extra data is cleared on your part.  In this case `TestFacade` is a `MonoBehaviour` so technically you need to tell Unity that you "destroyed" this object and want Unity to clean-up its part.  It's like calling `Font.Dispose` but you attempt to use it

Comment: ...also the notion of a _recyclable_ `MonoBehaviour` might be problematic.  I notice Zeninject hasn't been updated since the last major 2018 update.  Project looks pretty dead. :(

Comment: Ok, just checked through Zenject's Memory Pool Monitor (didn't know it existed) and indeed the pool persists. Ok, now I guess I need to rephrase the question to "How to destroy/clear/release pool in Zenject". I tried searching this info but got nothing. I really don't get it why it doesn't go with a scene and also I noticed that `TestFacade.Poo.MonoPoolableMemoryPool.OnDestroyed` doesn't get called when object is destroyed!

Comment: That’s a shame.  This is not the first buggy and abandoned “Unity compatible” GitHub project I’ve seen referenced here on SO. As for DI, as mentioned they have no place in games and there are better ways to do things.  Also, Unity dislikes anything that creates objects without it knowing (outside of typical script flow).